# Remover texto do elemento pai mantendo as filhas em BS4 no Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Como remover o texto indevido mantendo o titulo, paragrafo e link.

Codigo:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <header>
    <h1>
     Titulo
    </h1>
   </header>
   <p>Hello World</p>
   Texto Indevido
   <a href="">link</a>
  </body>
<html>
```

Esperado:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <header>
    <h1>
     Titulo
    </h1>
   </header>
   <p>Hello World</p>
   <a href="">link</a>
  </body>
<html>
```

Tentando obter somente o texto Indevido:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(codigo_html)
body = soup.body.text
print(body)
```

Resultado:

```
  Titulo
  Hello World
  Texto Indevido
  link
```

Comment: Por que não acessa o campo `text` do título apenas ao invés do `body`? `title = soup.body.header.h1.text.strip()`

Comment: Esse código é apenas um exemplo para simplificar, na pagina real preciso apagar o texto indevido mas nela contem varias tags dentro do corpo e no cabeçalho. Meu problema está em **apagar o texto indevido** que esta dentro da tags body e **manter a tag h1**

Comment: Mas se quer apenas o que está em `<h1>`, por que pegar todo o resto e apagar? O exemplo que dei pega somente o valor em `<h1>` tal como precisa; como não vem nada a mais, não precisa apagar.

Comment: Tentei deixar mais claro meu problema, nesse novo exemplo pegando somente do h1 me faria perder as demais informação. Se for o body eu pegaria o texto que não quero deixar no código.

Comment: Ok, agora ficou mais condizente. Agora a questão é: quais as condições que um texto deve satisfazer para ser considerado indesejado?

Comment: O texto é considerado indesejável a todo aquele que estiver fora de uma tag filha do body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma simples basta obter todas as tags e gerar um novo html com elas. Como o texto Indevido não é tag, não e colocada no novo codigo.

Para isso basta:

```
codigo_html = ''
for i in soup.find('body'):
    if "<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>" == str(type(i)):
        codigo_html = codigo_html + str(i)

soup = BeautifulSoup(codigo_html, 'html5lib')
```

O soup gerado em html5lib e contruido com toda estrutura html resultando em:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <header>
    <h1>
     Titulo
    </h1>
   </header>
   <p>Hello World</p>
   <a href="">link</a>
  </body>
<html>
```